# In Angular, I can't get my loading spinner to appear before longer running code finishes

Tags: angular

I'm pretty new to Angular. I would like to get a spinner gif to show up while my app is working on something. Here is the general idea: once a button is clicked, the function run() is executed. As it works for me right now, Angular will not update the dom until all of the code is completed, and by that time this.loading is set back to false, so the spinner never shows up.

Is there a way to force Angular to update the dom immediately after this.loading is set to true?

```
@Component(...)
export class myComponent {

  loading = false; // I have it working to when loading is set to true, the spinner will show up

  constructor() {}

  run(): void {
    this.loading = true;
    // update dom so that spinner shows up because this.loading is now true
    this.runAsync().then(() => {
      this.loading = false;
    });
  }

  async runAsync(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // do something that takes 5 seconds
      resolve();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess I should add that the async function isn't necessary in my question. I was doing that thinking Angular would move on to updating the dom by making the longer running code execute asynchronously. It didn't...

Comment: This should work. It's possible the image is slow to load though. Have you tried never setting it back to false to see if it ever shows at all?

Comment: Hi Dustin, if you provide a small solution where we can see the app running we will be able to point you in the right direction quicker. Maybe you can put something together really quick here: https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Hello @abney317...yes, if I don't set it back to false, the spinner stays.

Comment: @orlaqp Will do, never done that before...but I'll give it a shot

Comment: @orlaqp https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jelvzk?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @orlaqp I left "this.loading = false" commented out. If you let that run, you will not see the "would be spinner" show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run your example and the issue you are having is related to the way Angular process change detection. These are common ways used by angular to trigger change detection and update the view accordingly

- All browser events (click, mouseover, keyup, etc.)
- Timer functions: (setTimeout, setInterval)
- AJAX Requests

As you can see in your code none of that is happening because your loop does not generate any event. There are a few ways to make Angular trigger a change detection in this case. One way, use setTimeout, ex:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
})
export class AppComponent  {
  loading = false;

  run(): void {
    this.loading = true;

    this.runAsync().then(() => {
      this.loading = false;
    });
  }

  runAsync(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve();
      }, 2000)      
    });
  }
 }
```

Another way would be to manually ask angular to check for changes. Check here: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

The main thing here is to understand how change detection works and then make the framework work in your favor :-)

Please let me know if you need more details but this should help you understand what is going on here.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you @orlaqp! I’ll read up on that. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Awesome @DustinSelf, small request, if my answer solved your problem can you please go ahead and marked as an accepted answer? Thanks!